# Graphing and Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{1-x}{x})^x$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, graphing-functions

This question is a two-part question. So I have two problems.

**Problem 1**
Before I was evaluating this equation, I graphed the equation to see how it looked before making into a limit. This is what I got:
[image]

As you can see from the graph, the domain appears to be $\{X\in\mathbb{R}|0\le x \leq 1\}$ but that is wrong. As you can clearly see that is clearly wrong since there is a value of $x=2$ but it is not plotted on the graph. Same with $x=3,4,5...etc$.

What I don't understand is that why is $x=1.5$ is undefined and $x=1.4$ is defined. If I do the calculation by hand, I get the following resultant:

$$(\dfrac{1-x}{x})^x\qquad x=1.4$$

$$(\dfrac{1-1.4}{1.4})^{1.4}$$

$$(\dfrac{-0.4}{1.4})^{1.4}$$

$$Math\;Error\; appears\; on\; my\; calculator$$

Why does desmos state that at $x=1.4$, there is a value

**Problem 2**
My second is that I need to predict $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(\dfrac{1-x}{x})^x$. They I would do it would take out the highest exponent *(by looking for the highest exponent in the denominator)* from the numerator and denominator, but there is an exponent on the entire fraction, so I am stuck there. I did research on how to do it but I was unable to find an answer that would help for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is ill defined for $x>1$ (except for integer $x$), because then $(1-x)/x < 0$.
In this situation, one usually defines

$$a^b = \exp\big(b\,\text{Log}(a)\big)$$

where $\text{Log}$ is ***a*** complex logarithm.

In case you're not familiar with complex logarithms, here's a summary. $\exp$ is periodic in the complex plane: we have $\exp(2\pi i) = 1$, and hence $\exp(z + 2k\pi i) = \exp(z)$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$.
This means that the complex exponential does not admit a classical inverse, so the complex logarithm is 'multivalued'.
Indeed, we have

$$\exp^{-1}\left(re^{i\theta}\right) = \{\log(r)\,+i(\theta + 2k\pi)\mid k\in\Bbb Z\}.$$

When doing calculations with the complex logarithm, one chooses a *branch*.
Usually, the branch cut is done along the negative real axis; this is called the *principal branch* of the complex logarithm.

---

That your expression is ill defined it easy to see even if we ignore the underlying nuances of complex numbers.
In general, if $a<0$ and $q \in \Bbb Q\setminus\Bbb Z$, then $a^q$ is not well defined in the reals.

Say $q = m/n$ with $m,n\in\Bbb Z$.
Is $a^q = \sqrt[n]{a^m}$, or is it ${\left(\sqrt[n]a\right)}^m$?
Notice that if $n$ is even, then $\sqrt[n]a$ is not well defined, so the order matters (but ideally it shouldn't).

If we choose to define $a^q = \sqrt[n]{a^m}$, when $m$ is odd then $a^m<0$, so for even $n$ the root is still ill-defined.

And even if $n$ were odd, we still run into problems:
if $q=m/n$, then $q=(km)/(kn)$ for any $k\in\Bbb Z$.
In particular, we may choose $k$ even.
The value or 'well-definedness' of $a^q$ must not depend on a particular representation of $q$.

---

And after all this, there's the problem of defining $a^b$ for $b>0$ irrational.
This is usually done for $a>0$ via continuity: we show that $a^q$ is continuous on the positive rationals, and define

$$a^b = \lim_{\substack{q\,\in\,\Bbb Q\\q\,\to\,b}} a^q.$$

But if $a<0$, $a^q$ is ill defined on the rationals, so how do you define $a^b$?

---

If you require $x\in\Bbb N$ as $x\to\infty$, then we have

$${\left(\frac{1-x}x\right)}^x = {(-1)}^x\,{\left(1 - \frac1x\right)}^x. \tag{$*$}$$

A classical limit is $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\left(1 + \frac1n\right)}^n = e$.
Indeed, one often defines $e$ this way.
Now, consider

\begin{align}
{\left(1 + \frac1n\right)}^n \cdot {\left(1 - \frac1n\right)}^n
&=
{\left(1 - \frac1{n^2}\right)}^n \leqslant 1.
\end{align}

By Bernoulli's inequality, we have

$$
{\left(1 - \frac1{n^2}\right)}^n \geqslant 1-\frac1n,
$$

so by the squeeze theorem $\lim_{n\to\infty} {\left(1 + \frac1n\right)}^n \cdot {\left(1 - \frac1n\right)}^n = 1$.
It follows from the algebra of limits that $\lim_{n\to\infty} {\left(1 - \frac1n\right)}^n$ exists and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {\left(1 - \frac1n\right)}^n
=
\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty} {\left(1 + \frac1n\right)}^n}
= \frac1e.$$

Hence, even for integer $x$, the expression $(*)$ fails to have a limit: for even $x$, $(*)$ approaches $1/e$, while for odd $x$ it approaches $-1/e$.

Comment: This really complicated for me to understand since I am still in Grade.12

Comment: How do you define $(-2.7)^{3/4}$?

Comment: that is not possible to define. Since you can't find the fourth root of -2.7.

Comment: Then you have your answer. Your expression is not well defined for $x>1$ because you are trying to calculate the non-integer power of a negative real number.